# Focusing on element using Ember Components

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

I have an element which's height expands upon hover, however the page does not scroll down when the element extends beyond the view box.

I've heard using jquery to focus on the element upon mouseEnter allows this to work properly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  mouseEnter() {
    $(this).focus();
  }
});
```

I've just started using Ember and am not 100% on how components work, so any information is welcome.

Comment: Usually use Ember Jquery Aliase Ember.$ http://emberjs.com/api/#method__ or as @runspired said the component shortcut $()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  mouseEnter() {
    this.$().focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried that out and it's still not reacting appropriately. Any other ideas on what I can do?

Comment: @jakeinbake can you confirm the `mouseEnter` is triggered? (a console.log or debugger)

Comment: Nevermind, things are running smoothly now. Thanks again!